# Help identifying Star Wars set from troopers and white pieces

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, star-wars

My nephew handed down his LEGO pieces to my son. Most of them seem to be Star Wars. I need help to identifying them so I can download instructions.

Appreciate your help!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be mostly from one set with a mixture of Minifigs and accessories.

[*Set #10195-1 Republic Dropship with AT-OT*](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=10195-1).  (Referencing your picture, these are *generally* the bricks below your Minifigs.)

[image]

**Some Minifigs and accessories.**

*Set #8084-1 Snowtrooper Battle Pack*. (Referencing your picture, *some* of your Minifigs come from this set.)

[image]

**Headgear:** *Part 61182 Minifigure, Headgear Helmet SW Rebel Scout Trooper*. ( Comes with a black visor shown in your picture.  Headgear used on the figure directly below, which is *NOT* in your picture.)

[image]

[image]

**Trans-Neon Light Saber:** *Part #30374 Bar 4L (Lightsaber Blade / Wand)*.

[image]

**Chrome Hilt:** *Part #64567 Minifigure, Weapon Lightsaber Hilt Straight.*

[image]

**Minifig:** *Part #sw0178 General Maximillian Veers - Goggles Print and Dark Bluish Gray Helmet*.

[image]

**Minifig:** *Part #Sw0166 Shadow Trooper*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! You are amazing~